# XSLT issue with default namespace in XML

Tags: xml, xslt

This is hairdressing stuff! :)

What will it take to get those two node values out from the following XML doc?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AlarmSummaryMessage 
  xmlns:cbrn="http://www.site.com/cbrn" 
  xmlns:nc="http://www.site.com/nc" 
  xmlns:scr="http://www.site.com/src"
  xmlns="http://www.site.com/xmlns" xmlns:em="http://www.site.com/em">
  <MessageContent detectionEventKindCode="encounter">
    <AlarmingDevice>
      <EncounterDeviceID>Raid-WTC</EncounterDeviceID>
      <cbrn:EncounterDeviceID2>Raid-WTC</cbrn:EncounterDeviceID2>
    </AlarmingDevice>
  </MessageContent>
</AlarmSummaryMessage>
```

Using following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:template match="MessageContent">
    <xsl:text>DEVICE: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="AlarmingDevice/EncounterDeviceID/text()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AlarmSummaryMessage">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="MessageContent" />         
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your XML elments belong to a namespace, you will have to mention that namespace in the XSLT - something like the following will get you started:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.site.com/xmlns"
    xmlns:cbrn="http://www.site.com/cbrn">

        <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="tns:MessageContent" priority="2">
        <xsl:text>DEVICE:
        </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="tns:AlarmingDevice/tns:EncounterDeviceID"/>
        <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="tns:AlarmingDevice/cbrn:EncounterDeviceID2"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/tns:AlarmSummaryMessage" priority="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tns:MessageContent" />         
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please note the namespace definitions within the xsl:stylesheet tag and the prefixes in front of the node names.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstand your question, I believe that you are simply looking for the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/MessageContent/AlarmingDevice/EncounterDeviceID"/>
<xsl:value-of select="/MessageContent/AlarmingDevice/cbrn:EncounterDeviceID2"/>
```

Comment: I've updated the question with XSLT, which I've been using.. Similar to what you suggest, but it ain't working.. If you strip off all the namespaces from XML it works!

Comment: I agree with Dresden: add a <xsl:value-of select="AlarmingDevice/cbrn:EncounterDeviceID2"/> to your xsl; don't forget to include the namespace in your stylesheet: <xsl:stylesheet ... xmlns:cbrn="http://www.site.com/cbrn">